# Difference between const pointer and const array type in function parameter declaration

Tags: c, function-declaration

If I try to compile this small example:

```
void f(const int *a) {
    int * ptr = a;
    *ptr = 1;
}

void g(const int a[]) {
    int * ptr = a;
    *ptr = 1;
}
```

I get a warning for function `f` and an error for function `g`. I tried with gcc 9.3.0 and clang 10.0.0 and got very similar messages. Here the one from gcc:

```
main.c: In function ‘f’:
main.c:4:16: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    4 |     int* ptr = a;
      |                ^
main.c: In function ‘g’:
main.c:10:5: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘const int *’ and ‘int *’)
   10 |     *ptr = 1;
      |     ^
```

I know there is a difference between arrays and pointers, but I always believed there is no difference in function parameter declaration. And isn't using an array and a pointer as left hand operand in an assignment completely equivalent? After all I also thought that the following were interchangeable:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

**My questions:**

- What is the exact difference between `const int * a` and `const int a[]` in a function parameter declaration?
- Why do I get a warning in one of the cases and an error in the other?
- Shouldn't be both cases errors, because I try to change a `const` parameter?

**Edit**
as Paul Hankin pointed out I missed a semicolon in the original code. If added, both functions indeed give the same warning message, which is OK, since implicit pointer conversions (like in `ptr = a` discard const qualifiers.

Comment: I get exactly the same messages for both functions in both gcc and clang. Post the actual code you are compiling, or alternatively compile the actual code you are using. (Hint: save the source before compiling it.)

Comment: If you declare a function "takes some numbers which cannot be changed" and then attempt to change them, what exactly is the idea?

Comment: In the version you compiled you missed the semicolon off the line `int * ptr = a` in g?

Comment: @PaulHankin you're right. I did not even notice when typing the question here. Thanks!

Comment: So if the function declaration says it's not going to change the values, I am justified in feeding it data that resides in a read-only area. That is about the most important reason of `const` existing. This is what the compiler is warning about. Why are you "breaking the promise"?

Comment: I get the same error messages: https://www.godbolt.org/z/rjv5MT9Ma. Shouldn't the question be closed after all? It seems there is no questinon anymore.

Comment: @Cheatah: OP is quite aware that the code should not compile. It's about language lawyerism and quality of (compiler) implementation. (And turned out to be a typo in the first place, so feel free to add your close vote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get exactly the same messages for both functions in both gcc and clang. You have some typo in the code and didn't make a copy/paste when you posted it here.

> I always believed there is no difference in function parameter declaration.

This is true for plain 1D arrays. An array parameter such as `const int a[]` will get adjusted ("decay") into a pointer to it's first element. It is 100% equivalent to `const int* a`. Note that the `const qualifier` belongs to the pointed-at type, not the pointer itself.

Now as it happens, incomplete types such as arrays without a size cannot actually be used as function parameters if not for this array adjustment rule<sup>1)</sup>. It's the very reason why you can even type out an incomplete array type `[]` without size as a function parameter, because the type gets adjusted before the size of the array matters and the result is not an incomplete type but a pointer (to a complete type).

This equivalence doesn't scale well to 2D arrays however. An array parameter such as `const int a[x][y]` is an array of arrays. The first item is of array type `const int[y]`. So it gets adjusted to a pointer to such a type:
`const (*int)[y]`. This is *not* compatible with `const int*` nor with `const int**`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> C17 6.7.6.3

> After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.